# Stop loading posts when no more exist

Tags: wordpress, jquery

I'm using the following to load posts into a index page of a wordpress site. The problem is when it gets to the last page and there are no more posts to load. Its just keeps reloading the last page.

Any ideas of how I might stop this from happening? Thanks.

```
var $content = '#content';
var $nav_wrap = '.navigation';
var $anchor = '.navigation a.next';
var $text = 'Load More';

var $next_href = $($anchor).attr('href'); // Get URL for the next set of posts

$($nav_wrap).html('<a id="almc-load-more" href="' + $next_href + '">' + $text + '</a>');

$('#almc-load-more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), '', function(data) {
        var $timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        var $new_content = $($content, data).wrapInner('<div class="almc-loaded" id="almc-' + $timestamp + '" />').html(); // Grab just the content
        $next_href = $($anchor, data).attr('href'); // Get the new href

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $($nav_wrap).position().top}, 'slow'); // Animate scroll

        $($nav_wrap).before($new_content); // Append the new content
        $('#almc-' + $timestamp).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Animate load
        $('#almc-load-more').attr('href', $next_href);  // Change the next URL
        $('.almc-loaded ' + $nav_wrap).remove(); // Remove the original navigation
    });
});
```

Above code taken from here: http://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/jquery-script-for-loading-more-posts

Comment: store all links in an array instead

Comment: pass a value in data returned from server that indicates it's time to finish loading more items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment from Mr. Mayers (Thanks) I gave up on the code and used this tutorial:

http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

Has / does everything I needed.

Comment: Am I supposed to mark this answer as correct? Whats the etiquette?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastLink;

$('#almc-load-more').click(function(e) {
    if ( $anchor == $('.navigation a.next').last() ) {
        lastLink = 1;
    }

    if (lastLink == 1) {return} else {
        ...
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some code to check if the new href is different than the current href, and then only try to add a new post if they're different.  Then, if they aren't, you could have a message saying there are no more posts.

Comment: Yes. Good point. needs to have something to say 'No more posts'. I'll see what I come up with. Thanks